# Ruby/Rails method to insert stuff in string after x characters or words

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Which method has a function to insert something after x characters.

Example, I have this string:

```
@test = "Something, is wrong"
```

And then it would be possible to do something like:

```
@test.insert(x words or x characters , '<br />')
```

I need this because I need to insert a line break  `<br />` in a long string that I need to break up.

Comment: Aren't you answering your own question? The method String.insert is the one used for that purpose: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-insert

Comment: @fmendez - Hehe I see, ruby is very logic indeed.

Comment: This question could easily have been answered with a few tests in IRB, in less time than it took to type it in.

Comment: @theTinMan - I will just look at the documentation next for my questions.. I also find out that I was doing some overkill by using ruby to insert linebreak when I could use simple CSS to do the job.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should start by looking at the String class in the Ruby docs.. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html

Take a stab at what you think the method you're looking for might be called... in your case insert and see what it says..

```
"abcd".insert(3, 'X')    #=> "abcXd"
```

Comment: for x words you'd need to use a regex

Comment: Another option is `str[0..2] += "qwerty"`